# How to delay OpenMp parallel threads

Tags: opencv, openmp

After doing a bit of investigation on the internet it would seem that Videocapture objects from OpenCV are not multi thread safe. One suggestion I found was to delay the thread execution. How would I do this given the following example of a multi section in omp where I am essentially using the same Videocapture object everywhere:

```
  #pragma omp parallel{ 

  #pragma omp sections nowait
    { 
    #pragma omp section
    { loadframe }
    #pragma omp section
    { loadframe;}
    #pragma omp section
    { loadframe }
     }
   }
```

Comment: How about surrounding all uses of the OpenCV object in OpenMP `critical` constructs?

Comment: you are quite right, and I managed to get it working properly using the toy example below

Answer (score 0):

```
  MyClass* mc = new MyClass();
  #pragma omp parallel sections
  {
   #pragma omp section
   {
      #pragma omp critical
      {
             mc->myFunc();
      }
    }
      #pragma omp section
   {
        #pragma omp critical
         {
             mc->myFunc();
        }
  }
   }
```

[also, here is a decent example of do's and dont's](http://www.viva64.com/en/a/0054/#ID0EBCBM)